# collection_select misbehaving

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, selection

I have a form where the user selects a category from a drop-down list.  Here is the code in my view:

```
<%= collection_select(:project_categories, :id, Project_Category.all, :id, :category_name) %>
```

All the other fields in the form (yes, the collection_select is inside a form) save to and read from the database as expected.  But not the collection_select...

Here is the model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category,
  ...
  belongs_to  :user
  has_one     :category
  ...
end
```

The controller:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @project = current_user.build_project(params[:project])
  @project.save
  render 'edit'
end
...
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user
  @project.current_step = session[:step]
end
...
  private

  def correct_user
    @project = current_user.project
    redirect_to show_user_path if @project.nil?
  end

  def has_project
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Project_Category? What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to assign each project a category? If your relationships are set up correctly it should be something like:

```
<%= collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Your `Project` model will need a `:category_id` integer.